# stackless python constructor

Tags: python, python-stackless

```
import stackless
class MyTasklet(stackless.tasklet):
    def __init__(self, func, msg):
        pass

def foo():
    pass

msg = 'hello'
MyTasklet(foo, msg)()
```

I am using `stackless python`, this code generates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/workspace/python/test/klass.py", line 11, in <module>
    MyTasklet(foo, msg)()
TypeError: tasklet() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

It's very odd since I did not call the constructor of `stackless.tasklet`.

Anyone know what exactly the error is about.

Comment: The problem is that `stackless.tasklet` implements `__new__` and its `__new__` method accepts only an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the problem has to do with sub-classing `stackless.tasklet`, you could just make `MyTasklet` a callable `object` instead like follows:

```
import stackless
class MyTasklet(object):
    def __init__(self, func, msg):
        self.func = func
        self.msg = msg 

    def __call__(self):
      t = stackless.tasklet()
      t.bind(self.func)
      t.setup(self.msg)
      t.run()

def foo(msg):
  print msg 

msg = 'hello'
MyTasklet(foo, msg)()
```

EDIT: Alternatively you can just override `__new__` to pass the correct arguments to `stackless.tasklet.__new__`:

```
import stackless
class MyTasklet(stackless.tasklet):
  def __new__(cls, func, msg):
    return stackless.tasklet.__new__(MyTasklet, func)
  def __init__(self, func, msg):
    pass

def foo():
  pass

msg = 'hello'
MyTasklet(foo, msg)()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not asking for workarounds, I want to know why my code failed.

Comment: the reason you're code is failing is because `stackless.tasklet.__new__` takes only one parameter but you haven't overridden `__new__` in your subclass. I've edited my answer to reflect your request (i.e. a solution which keeps the subclassing)

Comment: got it, the constructor is in fact `__new__` not `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not subclass `stackless.tasklet`.

It is not how you are meant to use Stackless Python - and more importantly, it is difficult and overly complicated compared to the easier way.  Anything you need to do, you should be able to do in `f`, the function you run in the tasklet.  If you do really really want to subclass anyway, search for existing code examples, which will already give you a basic working tasklet subclass.

If you really want help with this, no-one with Stackless Python experience really answers questions here.  The Stackless Python mailing list is where they are.

Comment: subclassing `stackless.tasklet` is fine, one just have to know which methods to override if one is going to change the arguments to the constructor.